# Workspace Switching with gnome in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, workspaces, effects

I used the cube rotation effect in unity and liked it a lot. Is there a way to get a workspace switcher button in gnome?

Even without that I'd like to know how to get cube rotation back in gnome.
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>left</kbd>or<kbd>right</kbd> doesn't switch workspaces and I think compiz might be doing more cause <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>up</kbd>or<kbd>down</kbd> doesn't switch workspaces either and I think its supposed to in gnome.

I have 2 vertical and 4 horizontal in the compiz settings. and 4 using gnome-tweak-tool for workspaces. What should I do to straighten this out?

Comment: I think the problem lies in Ubuntu's switch to Gnome 3 instead of Unity.  I haven't installed the latest Ubuntu, so I have no experience in the matter.  Maybe you need to get Gnome 3 working with Compiz somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For workspace switcher, you have **Workspace Indicator** extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/.

[image: indicator]

For the cube animation, sorry I don't find any, but at least you can use **Workspace Grid** extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid.

For the CCSM, unfortunately, we cannot use it anymore in GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you can't switch workspaces at all? The default keybindings can be found and changed at `Settings > Devices > Keyboard` under `Navigation`. Don't know how to help with the cube effect, sorry.

Comment: I figured out how to change workspaces. My main issues is wanting the compiz software to work with gnome 3. I'm back in unity for that and some color grabbing software in kdenlive.